# Setting equal xlim and ylim in plot function

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to get the `plot` function to generate equal `xlim`and `ylim`automatically?
I do not want to define a fix range beforehand, but I want the `plot` function to decide about the range itself. However, I expect it to pick the same range for x and y.

Comment: Is this sufficient:  `x <- 1:11; y <- seq(11, 11*11, by=11); plot(x, y, xlim=range(x,y), ylim=range(x,y))`?

Comment: Well, it does :) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is to define a wrapper to the plot function:

```
plot.Custom <- function(x, y, ...) {
  .limits <- range(x, y)
  plot(x, y, xlim = .limits, ylim = .limits, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to manipulate interactively and then choose the right one. A slider will appear once you run the following code.

```
library(manipulate)
manipulate(
    plot(cars, xlim=c(x.min,x.max)),
    x.min=slider(0,15),
    x.max=slider(15,30))
```

Comment: Well, it is a really cool option and thank you for sharing it with me. However it does not solve my problem. I want to generate 100 plots for different datasets and I can not manipulate every single of them.

Comment: Well, you haven't mentioned that in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of anyway to do this using plot(doesn't mean there isn't one). ggplot might be the way to go; it lends itself more to be being retroactively changed since it is designed around a layer system.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Creating our ggplot object
loop_plot <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point()

#pulling out the 'auto' x & y axis limits
rangepull <- t(cbind(
        ggplot_build(loop_plot)$panel$ranges[[1]]$x.range,
        ggplot_build(loop_plot)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range))

#taking the max and min(so we don't cut out data points)
newrange  <- list(cor.min = min(rangepull[,1]), cor.max = max(rangepull[,2]))

#changing our plot size to be nice and symmetric
loop_plot  <- loop_plot + 
    xlim(newrange$cor.min, newrange$cor.max) + 
    ylim(newrange$cor.min, newrange$cor.max)
```

Note that the loop_plot object is of ggplot class, and wont actually print until its called.
I used the cars dataset in the code above to show whats going on, but just sub in your data set[s] and then do whatever postmortem your end goal is. 
You'll also be able to add in titles and the like based off of the dataset name et cetera which will likely end up producing a clearer visualization out of your loop. 
Hopefully this works for your needs.